# I'm trying to make a specific input into a text area call a specific javascript function, but it won't work

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid

So to give a little bit of detail, I'm trying to make an interactive fiction game or text adventure.  I have a form where all the "commands" for the game will be typed.  I'm working on the first command which is the string "start" to call a prompt.  Just to test the code, I have the prompt say "success!" when done correctly.  What's happening though, is as soon as I open the web browser to test, the prompt triggers before I even type a command.  Here's the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/engine.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="testForm"> <input type="text" name="">

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

And then here's the javascript.

```
var input = document.getElementById("testForm");

if (input = "start") {
    prompt("Success!");
}
```

Comment: You need to put your code into an event handler that runs when the user enters something in the form.

Comment: `if (input = "start") {` will always be true, and assign `"start"` to `input`. You mean `if (input == "start") {`

Comment: `var input = document.getElementById("testForm");` assigns the `<form>` DOM Element to 'input'. You need to select the `<input>` element instead.

Comment: You don't need `<form>` unless you're submitting the form to a server. If you're doing a browser app, you can just have `<input>` by itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/engine.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="testForm"> 
<input type="text" id="myInput">
</form>

<script>
 var myForm = document.getElementById("testForm");// get the form element.
 var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");// get the input element
 myForm.onsubmit = function() { // when the form is submitted, execute this function.
    if (myInput.value == "start") { // if the value of the input equals 'start', show prompt.
       prompt("Success!");
    }
    return false; //return false, so the form doesn't get submitted.
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
Added submit event handler, that returns false, so the form does not get submitted.

Comment: Down vote because you didn't explain anything, just showed code. Teach a man to fish and all that.

Comment: Well, I got mohamed's code to work, but...I still don't know why it works.

Comment: So, I realize you have to make 1 variable call the id, then, a second variable takes the actual input.  so what I'm confused on is why myForm.onsubmit needs to exist.

Comment: @DaniValentine so when you hit the ENTER  key, the form will be submitted, and then the code that checks for value equal to 'start' will be executed.

Comment: that makes more sense.

Comment: Using this code, I should still be able to create more than 1 requirement to work right?  For example if (myInput.value == "start" && currentRoom = true)    or something along those lines?  That way I can use the same form box throughout the entire game.

Comment: yes, but something like currentRoom == true, don't forget equals twice(==).

Comment: Gotcha, I appreciate the help from all of you.

Comment: @DaniValentine don't forget to mark the answer correct if it worked for you.

Comment: You may want to use alert instead of prompt if you are not asking the user for input.  ```alert('Success!');```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check the value of the input like so

```
var input = document.getElementById("inputID");
var value = input.value;
```

The code will always be ran straight away because it has no event handler. You could add a button which triggers it

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var input = document.getElementById("inputID");

  if (input.value === 'start') {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

Or if you prefer on the forms submit event:

```
document.getElementById('testForm').addEventListener('submit', function () {
  var input = document.getElementById("inputID");

  if (input.value === 'start') {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd prefer it to be by hitting enter, I always thought that forms don't go through until you hit enter.  I'll give it a shot now.

Comment: I have added the forms submit event to the answer

Comment: It's not working for me.  My code is now as follows.

Comment: Sorry, I can't upvote anything because I don't have the reputation.